# Is it recommended to save objects in Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an ASP.NET web application and I am thinking of saving the whole object `User` in Session instead of saving only the `UserId`.

Is it recommended? Will it cause low performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, saving the whole User object in Session instead of just the UserId will not cause performance problems. In fact, since you have the whole Object in Session, it may improve performance since you no longer need to go get it from the database.

As far as "is it recommended"? Well, that depends.

Using Sessions means that your site will now depend on that "state". So if you have multiple web servers with load balancing, you may have issues with the request of a customer going to one server and then the other. (Session is stored per server and not shared.)

So personally I would say:
If your site is small and will not require scaling to multiple servers, then go for it.

Comment: Scaling session state is easy using session state providers - there are ones for SQL Server, Redis, Memcached and others, all which allow multiple servers access to the same session state.

Comment: @Moo, yes, very true, there are multiple solutions to share sessions / cache objects. In that case however, now these objects must be transferred over the wire, in which case, the performance issue should be revisited.

Answer (score 1):

I agreed with previous answer . If you have
small site and number of users is limited ,
best to save user in session object.

When you are saving in session , you can configure type of repository for session,
it can be memory/SQL as well.

Default is memory as I recall and and if you
have plenty of users it can cause some problems .

Consider to use cache object where you can store user id and user object in dictionary .